# How to evaluate the following logarithm without using a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\log_{5}\sqrt[3]{5} + 2\log_{5}\sqrt{5}$

I did this: $\log_{5}5^\frac{1}{3} + \log_{5}(5^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

Then: $\log_{5}5^\frac{1}{3} +\log_{5}5^1$

$=\frac{1}{3}\log_{5}5 + \log_{5}5$

What next? How do I evaluate them without a calculator?

Comment: $\log a+\log b=\cdots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have missed that you have already found the solution. Anyway, to clear up your confusion, I would like to show an expression that will help you understand that.
$$\log_ba=k \implies b^k=a$$

You have something similar,
$$\log_55=k\implies 5^k=5$$
which is only possible when $k=1$.So, $\log_55=k=1$.

Comment: yeah, got it! Thanks a lot! @Hawk

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\displaystyle \log_a a = 1$, provided that $a$ is a valid value.